# .babelrc `ignore` option is not ignoring the files that I want to be ignored

Tags: babeljs

So the title pretty much explains my problem. I don't want babel to be transpiling some files that are nested within my folder structure, but I can't get it to work.

my babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets" : ["es2015",  "react", "stage-0", "es2017"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-regenerator",
    "transform-async-to-generator",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": ["react-hmre"]
    }
  },
  "ignore": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "public",
    "src/client",
  ]
}
```

And my babel packages:

```
{
"babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
"babel-core": "^6.25.0",
"babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
"babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.23.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.22.0",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0","babel-register": "^6.18.0",
}
```

Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

I believe you can do this through the CLI, but I'd much rather do it through the .babelrc file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add `--no-copy-ignored` param to the end of your build script

```
babel src --out-dir lib --copy-files --no-copy-ignored
```

If you're using .babelrc or .babelrc.json, add ignore section to the root;

```
  "ignore": [
    "**/*.test.js"
  ]
```

Note: Tested on `Babel 7.x`

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/5532#issuecomment-288755557:

> There are some issues with ignore/only that we are fixing in 7.0

You could see if Babel 7 works well enough for you! According to [their blog](https://babeljs.io/blog/2017/09/12/planning-for-7.0), it seems like it's working fine.

Otherwise, you might just be stuck doing it through the CLI for now.

https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/5487 seems to be the PR that fixed this issue for Babel 7.x.